# Dispatcher.Run vs Dispatcher.PushFrame

Tags: wpf, dispatcher

I have a non-ui thread that I need to pump messages on.

The normal way to do this would involve a call `Dispatcher.Run()` in the thread proc of my thread.

I'd like to modify this to make it more robust with regard to unhandled exceptions.

My first cut is:

```
   for (;;)
    {
        var frame = new DispatcherFrame();
        try
        {
            Dispatcher.PushFrame(frame);
            break;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            frame.Continue = false;
            Log("ThreadProc caught exception:\n{0}", e);
        }
    }
```

This code works and allows the dispatcher to continue pumping messages after an exception.

Does anyone know of any potential problems with this approach?

Answer (score 0):

I find using a dispatcherframe can give some problems when using it with a ui thread - for example problems with focus - I think your scenario will be fine.

Have you tried catching it with:

Application.DispatcherUnhandledException

or

Dispatcher.UnhandledException

You could also try that and set Handled=true to make it continue.

Comment: The problem with the top level exception notifiers is that by the time we handle the exception, the dispatcher on the helper thread seems to already be toast.